# How to apply multiple condition in same column in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Here I want to apply muplitile condition in same column but using countifs not getting proper output.
Excel Values: -

```
Column 1          Column 2
Y                   a
Y                   b
Y                   c
Y                   d
N                   s
N                   b
```

Tried Formula : 
=SUM(COUNTIFS(B:B,{"a","b"}))

Expected output : - 2

Udpated Question : - above in addition I want in Column 1 Should be filter with "Y" and in Column 2 filter with "a","b" and output should come : - 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this function is for multiple ranges.

i.e. where column a = 'a' AND column b = 'a'

 since column a can never = 'a' and 'b' this will result in 0

try this instead.

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"a")+(COUNTIF(A:A,"b"))
```

or for multiple conditions in the same range you can do this.

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,{"a","b"})
```

but this produces 2 arrays for each condition "a" and "b" so these need to be summed

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,{"a","b"}))
```

additional conditions on other columns can be added to the COUNTIFS function the normal way

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(B:B,{"a","b"},A:A,"y"))
```

Comment: Here I provided you sample codes and actually having more than 20 codes so is there any better way like or oeprator

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys.But here in addition I wanna add one more condition in Column 1 with "Y"

Answer (score 1):

Here Simply I have added one more Condition in provided solution.

=SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,"Y",B:B,{"a","b"}))

And gotta answer.

Thanks for reply.